# Range control dec to hex with spesific range

Tags: php

I'm working with a slider control. I'm trying to do a decimal to hex or not exactly, it is a regular number range without a decimal point. And for reference:

- `0` is zero
- `00` is `100`
- `50` is `50`

***(meaning the numbers are always 1 or 2 digits only on the slider control.)***

***(and the hex also needs to be only 2 digits.)***

I know about `dechex`. Is that what I would use for this? Or if its not a number with a decimal point is there another command other than dechex for this.

And how do I set the range to only manage the control from `0` to `00`?

I am learning. I don't have a clue how to write the php so any and all comments might help. Thanks for the help! Any questions let me know too.

Comment: How can you know if `50` is decimal 50 or decimal 80 expressed in hexadecimal?

Comment: Can you give some example inputs and the expected output? Other than the special case for "00", I'm not sure what you want that dechex _wouldn't_ do.

Comment: I think possibly you've confused [different meanings of the word "decimal"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_(disambiguation)). When the manual says `dechex` "converts decimal to hexadecimal", it is talking about base 10 (and base 16), nothing to do with fractions or decimal points.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

function convert($s) {
    print "CONVERT: $s\n";
    $s = "X".$s;
    switch($s) {
        case "X00":
            return dechex(100);
            break;
        case "X0":
            return null;
            break;
        default:
            return dechex(substr($s,1));
            break;

    }
}

print convert('0')."\n";
print convert('1')."\n";
print convert('50')."\n";
print convert('99')."\n";
print convert('00')."\n";
```

output:

```
CONVERT: 0

CONVERT: 1
1
CONVERT: 50
32
CONVERT: 99
63
CONVERT: 00
64
```

PHP does do some automatich type conversion, and does not know the difference between "0" en "00", that's why I am adding an "X" in front of it to know the difference (and I am comparing strings).

P.S.: some changes might need to be done to meet your exact expectations...

Comment: You can use `===` in an if statement rather than switch to avoid the "type juggling", i.e. `if ( $s === '00' ) { ... } else { ... }`

Comment: @IMSoP: Thanks for the info. I am not using PHP enough, but this one is worth remembering..... 